# MongoDB Shard Zone Range Overlapping

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I am configuring a test mongo setup with 2 shards, and I'm trying to add zone ranges to each shard:

`sh.updateZoneKeyRange('mydb.test', {id:MinKey,ts:MinKey}, {id:MaxKey,ts:1548787704000}, 'cold')`

`sh.updateZoneKeyRange('mydb.test', {id:MinKey,ts:1548787704000}, {id:MaxKey,ts:MaxKey}, 'hot')`

First command runs fine, but second tells me:

`Zone range: { id: MinKey, ts: 1548787704000.0 } -->> { id: MaxKey, ts: MaxKey }  on  hot is overlapping with existing: { id: MinKey, ts: MinKey } -->> { id: MaxKey, ts: 1548787704000.0 }  on  cold`

I thought the maximum bounds were exclusive and minimum bounds inclusive?

Comment: Duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/258466/mongodb-shard-zone-range-overlapping

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit your comment will probably discourage people from responding as they might think it was already answered somewhere else. Might be more useful to mark it as duplicate *after* someone answers as then people searching on either community can find what they're looking for.